# Adding icons to the ActionBar on Android

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

Im following the next tutorial: [Adding Action Buttoms](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html), I did it step by step but when I run my app doesn´t shows any icon. I was debugging but everything seems correct and I have any nullPointerException or something like that.

This is my mainActivity:

```
package com.training.training.appone;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "          com.        training.example.appone.MESSAGE";
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);


 }


 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my, menu);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activiy_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void sendMessage(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    // El primer parametro es el KeyName:
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

And I put this XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
        <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
        <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
        <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
    </menu>
```

I have an error in the last line "android:showsAsAction="never", I have the libray downloaded and referenced in my build gradle: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0' I also tryed changed "android" to "res-auto", but it says that the items must have a title (they have them):

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/res-auto">
  <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
  <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
  <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
  <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:showAsAction="never" />
   </menu>
```

My library:

[image: AppCompat]

In this point I have no idea what happends.

Comment: I fixed the XML file (thanks to Stuard Robenson) but the actionBar does not shows the icons yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the following changes in your menu.xml

```
<menu 
       ....
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    ...
    app:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

And if you want to display your menu on actionBar then it should be `app:showAsAction="always"`.

Answer (score 2):

In your XML file, Please change this line

```
app:showAsAction="always"
```

instead of

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably as you are using AppCompat library, you should use

```
app:showAsAction="never"
```

instead

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

Comment: what you have used in root tag that tag name you need to use for child.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the xml schemas in the tutorial you have both:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Notice the **xmlns:android** and **xmlns:yourapp** are different. So all you need to do is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          yourapp:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

The **android** and **yourapp** tags can be named however you want. They are just a named reference to the schema.

Comment: I used this, now I don´t have errors, but a the actionBar doesn´t shows icon yet.

Comment: Does the action_search id show up in the overflow? It could be that there isn't enough room on your device to show it in the action bar.